# How do I populate a field in a mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
var posting = new Posting({
  content: fields.content,
  creator: req.user,
});

posting.save(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    res.status(501).json({ error: err });
  } else {
    res.json({ posting: posting });
  }
});
```

The posting model has `creator` field which represents an instance of the `User` model. The `Post` instance is returned in JSON form after it has been saved. But the returned `Post` instance doesn't contain data from the corresponding `User` object in its `creator` field. It sends only the id value of the `User` instance.

How do I populate the `creator` field before sending the response?

Comment: Inside save callback, try to call `User.populate(posting.creator)` before return the result. More details about populate [here](http://devdocs.io/mongoose/api#model_Model.populate). Let me know if this works so I can answer your question.

Comment: did not work. i tried this as well: User.populate(posting, { path: 'creator', model: 'User' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `.populate` method of the `Posting` model on the `posting` instance:

```
posting.save(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    res.status(501).json({ error: err });
  } else {
    // Populate the 'posting' object's 'creator' field.
    Posting.populate(posting, { path: 'creator', model: 'User' }, function (err, posting) {
      res.json({ posting: posting });
    });
  }
});
```